# $\sigma$-Algebra: Why do we want it to contain complements as well?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Everybody Hello, I was always wondering:
(Please answers apart from historical reasons)

- Why do we want a $\sigma$-Algebra to possess more than just its crucial disjoint $\sigma$-union property? Say, why do we want it to contain the complements as well?
- Would it be fine to restrict for first attempt on the disjoint $\sigma$-union property and then define a measure as a $\sigma$-additive set function?

*...moreover, I would be appeased if one requires additionally that it contains the empty set and the whole space...I mean, some authors like Dunford and Schwartz follow this "purer" route.*

Comment: Without complements, measure theory wouldn't work for probability: if you know the probability that something occurs is $p$, you need to be able to say the probability that it doesn't occur is $1-p$.  Complements also give you intersections, so if $A$ and $B$ are events, you can discuss them both happening.  You might not be able to build a theory of integration with just countable disjoint additivity (although I'm skeptical), but I imagine that the few additional examples the theory produced would be too ill behaved to care.

Comment: Yes, for sure if you're concerned with propability theory certainly you'de like to have complements and intersections but why then countable unions??? Or why only finite intersections and not also countable or even arbitrary intersections? Same for unions??? It would seem naturally to say a probabilistic space should! be one that contains FINITE unions, FINITE intersections and complements and thats it!

BUT!!! if you're concerned with integration theory you certainly don't need those things?! In return your theory could become even richer if avoiding closedness under complements...

Comment: Btw, for infinite measure spaces the interpretation $P(A^c)=P(\Omega)-P(A)$  does not even make sense for $A$ and $A^c$ both being of infinite size -.-

Comment: What do you mean "Or why only finite intersections and not also countable or even arbitrary intersections?"  In a $\sigma$-algebra you have countable unions and countable intersections.  It's a topology that has arbitrary unions but only countable intersections.  And why would you want to limit yourself to finite things for a probability space, it's not like you can't have infinite probability spaces (e.g., flip a coin an infinite number of times, or continuous time stochastic processes like brownian motion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As preliminary answer we want to deal especially with probability theory and stochastic processes where complements constitute essential parts of the theory ...so when considering measure theory we'd like to include complements right from the beginning ...however for pure integration theory sigma algebras seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

While not an answer per se, here is an example to get you thinking about why you might want more than countable disjoint unions.

Consider the space $[0,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$, and take as your "algebra" the sets of the form $[0,x)$.  The only step functions on this space contain only one step, and the sum of two step functions will not in general be measurable.

It's one thing to have a theory where a space has very few measurable functions.  It is quite another to have a theory where you can't even add measurable functions.

Comment: Yes, but, integration would be possible in this case too similar to continuity in spaces with trivial topology even though these are not very interesting examples; but still that doesn't drive us to strengthen the axioms as one doesn't in topology

Answer (score 0):

There is a textbook by Halmos, *Measure Theory*, in which he does as much as possible in the setting of $\sigma$-rings, where complements are not assumed.  But subsequent mathematicians have not adopted that point of view.

(1) In the Halmos definitions, we can postulate that every measurable set is $\sigma$-finite; then when (rarely) it is necessary, extend things to non-$\sigma$-finite sets.

(2) In the non-Halmos definitions, we postulate that the collection of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, then when (rarely) it is necessary, state theorems for $\sigma$-finite sets.

Each system has some advantages, some simplifications that occur.  But mathematians have chosen system (2).

Comment: In Halmos's book, while he might not assume general complements, he does have differences and all countable unions (not just disjoint ones).  This does not feel to me to be a significant weakening of usual $\sigma$-algebras, and in particular is assuming much more than just countable disjoint unions.

Comment: Yes, I looked it up to and it doesn't seem to be a weakening at all according to the discussion above